# Weird naming of shared dashboards in azure

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

In our org. we have a lot of dashboards, but whenever a dashboard is shared they get a strange GUID-like name in the 'browse dashbords' view. For instance, if I created a private dashboard 'my-dashboard' and then shared it to the org, it would be renamed something like 'f0562n-23edj9-298dnd (my-dashboard)'. Does anyone have tips on how to keep it in a human-readable format?

I've tried clicking around to find a better view of the dashboard names, where they are referred to only by the human-given names.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Shared Dashboards" view the "Name" column contains a guid-like identifier, and the "Go to Dashboard" column contains the name of the actual dashboard.  I clicked on "Manage view" to try to reorder or remove the "Name" column but it appears that it can't be reordered or removed.  If you don't see the "Go to dashboard" column with the original name of the dashboard you could Manage the view and add the column, but I don't see a way to remove the guid-like name column from being shown first.